# ActionBar and CustomView - home button

Tags: java, android

I want to have a CustomView on my ActionBar that will define buttons, logos, etc. But I also want to make use of the Home Button and the ability to search in the ActionBar via a Search Interface. Is it possible to add, i.e. Home Button with icon on an ActionBar with Custom view layout?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible to use a custom view on the action bar. The Strava android app does just that (or at least gives the appearance of an action bar at the top that has a non-standard layout).

Addressing your requirements one at a time: You can inflate a view of your own and assign it to the action bar:

```
View customView= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customView, null);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customView);
```

What you put in your view is, naturally, entirely up to you but you will have to manage everything yourself, including the home button actions. This includes the icon and text for the home button on the left hand side and search functionality. On a small device (especially in portrait mode) I'd go for a search icon only but on devices with more real estate you could fit a text input field in as well, using the alternative layouts feature to automatically pick up the most appropriate view for the device.

Comment: So you're saying that I can use Custom view for an ActionBar and also show the Home button just like on normal ActionBar? Because by using a custom view for the actionbar the Home button is not visible (is covered by the custom view actually.